# Auto-increment a field with leading 0's in MongoDB schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am implementing a MongoDB schema for invoices.

I would like to know how I could increment the `id` field on insert?

The catch is i need the id to have leading 0's.

For example, the first invoice in the system should have the following ID:

> 0000001

I need this to be able to display the invoice sequence number to the user.

```
var InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
/*  invoiceId: {
    type: Number
  },
*/ 
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Paid', 'Unpaid']
  },
  net: {
    type: Number
  },
  vat: {
    type: Number
  },
  total: {
    type: Number
  },
  products: [{
    product: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      trim: true
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      trim: true
    },   
    quantity: {
      type: Number
    },
    unitCost: {
      type: Number
    },
    vat: {
      type: Number
    },
    total: {
      type: Number
    }
  }],
  billingDetails: [BillingDetails],
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
});
```

Comment: are you using mongoose?

Comment: did any answer solved your problem or is it still unsolved?

Comment: @EnriqueFueyo still unsolved - waiting for more ideas

Comment: @martynas It would help if you described why Enrique's answer doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one plugin (that I haven't used) called [mongoose-auto-increment](https://github.com/codetunnel/mongoose-auto-increment) which would handle the auto-increment.

If you want to code it by yourself for this specific situation you can follow this [MongoDb tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) which seems to be pretty straightforward.

It should be something like:

```
var InvoiceSchema = new Schema({..})
InvoiceSchema.pre('save', function (done) {
  if (this.isNew){ //new Record => create
    //this function is the one that should do the FindAndModify stuff
    getNewId(function(autoincremented_id){
      this.id=autoincremented_id;
      done()
    })
  }else{
    done()
  }
});
```

For the leading 0's I would recommend to use virtuals. let's suppose you want 7 digits:

```
InvoiceSchema.virtual('formattedId').get(function () {
  return ("0000000"+this.id).slice(-7);
});
InvoiceSchema.virtual('formattedId').set(function (arg_id) {
  this.id = parseInt(arg_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As i know mongo is not supporting auto increment. but you can do small trick. 
When you insert item you Use FшndAndModify Query and store new id in other collection. Example was [posted on mongodb blog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)